# javascript get value of input which is a div in a div without id

Tags: javascript, html

i can not change the html part of the project
i just can change the js
i suppose to get the value of the input which is the div in the div with no id

for example like this:

```
<div id="s-Input_1" class="pie text firer commentable non-processed"  datasizewidth="235px" datasizeheight="40px" dataX="117" dataY="39" ><div class="backgroundLayer">
</div>
<div class="paddingLayer">
<div class="content">
<div class="valign">
<input type="text"  value="Productid" maxlength="100"  tabindex="-1" placeholder=""/>
</div>
</div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

and

```
  alert(document.getElementById("myText").value);
```

[image]

Comment: Use `document.querySelector()`

Comment: There's no element with the id `myText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use querySelector. Here is what you need.

```js
alert(document.querySelector(".valign>input").value)
```

```html
<div id="s-Input_1" class="pie text firer commentable non-processed"  datasizewidth="235px" datasizeheight="40px" dataX="117" dataY="39" ><div class="backgroundLayer">
</div>
<div class="paddingLayer">
<div class="content">
<div class="valign">
<input type="text"  value="Productid" maxlength="100"  tabindex="-1" placeholder=""/>
</div>
</div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the id for the input

Then this section here can read the value in it

alert(document.getElementById("myText").value)

Comment: The frist sentence in the question starts with: _"i can not change the html part of the project..."_

Answer (score 0):

You can use getElementsByTagName to get the elements without id.

```
alert(document.getElementByTagName("input")[0].value);
```